# Entity Framework Search On Entity Property and Entity ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework 6 with C#.

My tables are like;

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ProductInfos = new List<ProductInfo>();
    }

    ...

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductInfo> ProductInfos { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInfo
{
    ...

    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to search text in `Product.Name` and `Product.ProductInfos` -> `Name`.
Like;

```
                    queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchtext))
                                         .Where(p => p.ProductInfos.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchtext)));
```

However as you can see my brain has been stopped :)
How can query a class's property and child classes properties ?

P.s. This is not big tables, don't worry about performance errors. I have only 50 products.

Comment: What is the error? What is the result? Did you test your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchtext) || 
                                 x.ProductInfos.Any(y => y.Name.Contains(Seachtext));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.